# Azure deployment pipeline: add release version to configuration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-deployment

We're building our first Azure-based web application using ASP.NET core 3.1 and Azure Devops plateform.

My boss asked me is it was possible to add the "release number" (his words) to the application itself.

I was thinking of writing the build ID in a configuration setting of the application and displaying that but I'm afraid I have no idea how to get that number and write it to the app setting from a release pipeline.

Would anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch) you have list of predefined variables for release pipeline.

You may use `Release.ReleaseId` or `Release.ReleaseName`. To put this value into app settings you may use [replace token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

For default settings you need to put `#{Release.ReleaseName#}` as value of setting in your file.